# Collection.sort(list) is also sorting or reversing my older lists such as mList, myList

Tags: java, android

I've two lists one is used for storing the raw data and another one is used for sorted data. In this case,

```
//Used to store the sorted and reversed data
sortedList = new ArrayList<>();

//Assigning mList raw data in a new list
sortedList = mList;

//Here, I'm sorting and reversing
Collections.sort(sortedList);
Collections.reverse(sortedList);
```

And sortedList is now sorted and reversed but the problem is that mList is also sorted itself. Why? And how should I sort the only one list instead the older lists. Help Help HElp. Any Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Because `sortedList` and `mList` both are holding the same reference.

Comment: Not directly to your question, but instead of sorting and then reversing; I would sort in reverse order to begin with. Like, `Collections.sort(sortedList, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Comment: You have *one* list, referenced by two variables. Sorting it therefore sorts it.

Answer (score 4):

Your sort operation is being done on the same reference which refers to the original list.  One workaround would be to copy the original list via the copy constructor:

```
sortedList = new ArrayList<>(mList);
Collections.sort(sortedList);    // doesn't affect mList
Collections.reverse(sortedList); // also doesn't affect mList
```